# Saving a counter in libGDX

Tags: android, libgdx, screen, overlap, bounds

I am developing a game in libgx for android.
I have a counter on the screen that increase when i touch something.
In that game you can die, but i want to save the highest score that the player had.
I don't know where to begin with. I am new to android game development.
this is the method when u die.

```
if (player.getBounds().overlaps(rock.getBounds()){
        System.out.println("Game Over");
    }
```

And here i increase the counter

```
        if (player.getBounds().overlaps(food.getBounds()) {
            System.out.println("Food");
            counter++;
                        }
```

Thankyou

Comment: Couldnt you just write it in a file?

Comment: Sir, i really don't know much about libgdx. I'll really appreciate if you could help me with this.

Comment: @user2959870 Look at the [File module](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-module). Sadly, there is no tutorial for writing files... It should not be too difficult to find how do this by your own, looking at [`FileHandle`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandle.html) javadoc

Comment: Yeah. Read the highscore on create. If the player gets a highscore, write it in the file. Should be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you need are Preferences. They provide a platform independent way of saving small amounts of data. They are ideal for stuff like high scores.

Call loadPrefs() to load from storage and  savePrefs() to save them back.

```
public static Preferences prefs;  
public static int counter;    // The variable you want to save

//Save the shared preferences
public static void savePrefs(){
    prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("game-prefs");  // The name of your prefs files
    prefs.putInteger("counter", counter);    //counter is your counter you wish to save. "counter" is the name of the varable saved in shared preferences


    prefs.flush();  //Save preferences
}

//Load the shared preferences

public static void loadPrefs(){

    prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("game-prefs");
    counter = prefs.getInteger("counter",0)  //Load counter, default to zero if not found

}
```